# how to trim an output variable in jenkinspipeline groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a code

```
 def author_email = bat(returnStdout:true,  script:'git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%%ae')
 def author= "${author_email}".trim()
 echo "author E-mail is ${author}"
```

I am getting output as

***author E-mail is E:\jenkins\slave\workspace\jobs_testdb_test_branch_2>git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ae 
username@domain.com***

but I would like to get an output as below:

*author E-mail is username@domain.com*

How can I trim the unnesseary characters from the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much of a jenkins pipeline issue but more a Windows Batch programming issue.

In a batch file you can either use `@echo off` to get rid of the echoing of the command or you can add it `@` in front of the individual commands.

In your case you can do this and it will fix your problem:

```
def author_email = bat(returnStdout:true,  script:'@git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%%ae')
def author= "${author_email}".trim()
echo "author E-mail is ${author}"
```